# Clarification on "userPrincipalName" property in Intune Graph API and Intune admin center

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, intune, microsoft-graph-intune

I'm currently working with the Intune Graph API and the Intune admin center for device management. I have come across the "userPrincipalName" property in the GET /deviceManagement/managedDevices endpoint, which is stated to represent the device's user principal name (UPN).

However, I would like to confirm its specific usage and behavior, particularly in relation to the primary user associated with the device. I have seen conflicting information regarding whether the "userPrincipalName" property refers to the enrolled by user or the primary user.

Based on my research and discussions, here are the key points I have gathered:

1. Initially, I understood that the "userPrincipalName" property in the Intune Graph API refers to the user who enrolled the device, commonly known as the "enrolled by" user.
2. However, it has been suggested that the "userPrincipalName" property might actually represent the UPN of the primary user associated with the device.

To seek clarity and confirm the correct usage of the "userPrincipalName" property, I would greatly appreciate it if someone with knowledge and experience in working with the Intune Graph API and the Intune admin center could provide some insights or official documentation references.

Answer (score 0):

If you query deviceManagement/managedDevices/{deviceID}/users, then userPrincipleName property refers to the primary user.

If you query deviceManagement/managedDevices/{deviceID}/$select=userPrincipalName, it refers to the user who enrolled the device.